# Android SQLite wildcard to select character pattern

Tags: android, sqlite, wildcard

I am using an SQLite database in Android. I want to query the database using a query like

`SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE City LIKE '%nes%'`

which would return the city `Sandnes` based on the character pattern 'nes' matching, as in: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp.

However, when I try to put this into android's

`query (SQLiteDatabase db, String[] projectionIn, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String sortOrder)`

method, using

`selection = KEY_CODE + " LIKE ?";` and `selectionArgs = new String[] {"'%" + query + "%'"};`,

I get no results returned.

Can I do this in the android query? If so, how should I write it? And if not, is there an alternative way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The way you do it should work. Please post more complete example of what you are doing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're building a "likeable" parameter that looks like this:

```
'%do you like me%'
```

The apostrophes should not be there: they belong to literal syntax, not to a pattern itself:

```
%now you like me%
```

Use

```
selectionArgs = new String[] {"%" + query + "%"};
```